# Creating a border like this using :before And :after Pseudo-Elements In CSS?

Tags: css, border, pseudo-element

## Objective

I want to be able to create a border like [this](http://lifeofstrange.com/footer.jpg) in css, maybe using pseudo elements then a background image.

## Code

### HTML

```
<div id="footer"></div>
```

### CSS

```
#footer {
    background: #4b4b4b;
    color: #868686;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 900px;
}

#footer:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 220px;
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    height: 8px;
}
```

Comment: Will get a jsfiddle for you, i managed to get the :before to output the first border.

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MattStrange/wq4eT/)

Comment: Don't use id's for CSS! It blows away the specificity!!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

See the following snippet, is this what you want?

```css
body {
    background: silver;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

#content:after {
    height: 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    background: #808080;
    border-right: 1px white;
    content: '';
}

#footer:before {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    background: silver;
    height: 10px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: 101px;
}

#content {
    background: white;
}


#footer {
    padding-top: 10px;
    background: #404040;
}

p {
    padding: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

#footer p {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="content"><p>#content</p></div>
    <div id="footer"><p>#footer</p></div>
</body>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/breadadams/byepuec1/)

Answer (score 5):

```
#footer:after
{
   content: "";
    width: 40px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #529600;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer? Posting only code is often not enough.

Comment: this code set  :after Pseudo-Elements In CSS for h4.

Comment: @VirendraYaduvanshi - it does not. it applies :after-Elements to the element with id "footer".